# ASP.NET Databinding a DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net

Greetings Gurus,

I have an ASP.Net app that I'm working on with a editable detailsview.
There is a boundfield in the detailsview called Status which I turned into a template field.

This templatefield (specifically the editItemTemplate) was changed to a dropdownlist with a unique datasource. How do I Bind this dropdownlist to the StatusField so my update query picks up it's value when I click update?

```
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListStatus" runat="server"
DataSourceID="Status_DataSource"  DataTextField="Status" DataValueField="Status">
</asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind to controls from a template field. You need to read the value (using FindControl to find your DropDownListStatus and read its value) and set it for the update query manually in your update method.